How to fix "Format the efi partition as fat 32 with dual-boot linux and windows on an sdd disk with gpt
This is the error

I have my partition 1 for efi that uses linux and my partition 2 of 120 GB where linux is installed, the rest was created by the windows 10 installer

, it has never happened to me before. My disk is SSD GPT. Can it be solved without having to format the entire disk? Any help?

"Can it be solved without having to format the entire disk?" - No; You have to do exactly what the notification message indicates: delete the NTFS EFI partition and create a FAT32 EFI partition. Doing that will prevent your ability to boot into Windows and Linux.

EFI should always be formatted as FAT32 (there is no reason to format it as NTFS AFAIK)
